# Dynamic fan out with Akka Streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am building an Akka Streams application that goes through a couple of steps. There is one particular step that produces 0 or more results, it is not known in advance how many there are. Each of the results has to be processed asynchronously (by the same kind of component) and finally all the results have to be merged.

How should I model this in Akka Streams? I noticed that GraphDsl has a Broadcast element that lets you model a fan out, however this seems to be only possible when the number of outlets is know in advance.
Is there a way in Akka Streams to have something like Broadcast but that fans out to a dynamic number of outlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `mapConcat` does what I want. Here's a POC:

```scala
package streams

import scala.concurrent._
import akka._
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import scala.util.Random

object StreamsTest extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import system.dispatcher

  case class SplitRequest(s: String)

  def requestHandlerWithMultipleResults(request: SplitRequest): List[String] = 
   request.s.split(" ").toList

  def slowProcessingTask(s: String) =  {
    Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(5000))
    s.toUpperCase
  }

  val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val source: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source(List(SplitRequest("january february march april may")))
      .mapConcat(requestHandlerWithMultipleResults)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(5)(s => Future(slowProcessingTask(s)))

    val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

    source ~> sink

    ClosedShape
  })

  g.run()
}
```

Output, e.g:

```scala
MAY
JANUARY
FEBRUARY
MARCH
APRIL
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out *Hubs* in this page: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala

> There are many cases when consumers or producers of a certain service (represented as a Sink, Source, or possibly Flow) are dynamic and not known in advance. The Graph DSL does not allow to represent this, all connections of the graph must be known in advance and must be connected upfront. To allow dynamic fan-in and fan-out streaming, the Hubs should be used.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I still don't see how a broadcast- or merge hub would solve my issue. In the code example that is given in the link, the producer still invokes the consumer an explicit number of times.